# Flutter - What to log and how to save to could or database?

Tags: flutter, dart, logging, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to implement logging in my Flutter App. I watched a few videos that give an idea on how to go about it. However, I couldn't find a video that shows what (other than error messages) all things should be logged. Should I insert a log in every function?

This does give some idea though.
[To Log Or To Not Log?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976469/to-log-or-to-not-log)

Another question that I have is how to save these logs to DB or cloud? I am using Flutter logger package. But it does not have the feature to upload to cloud. Do I need to use something like Sentry or Firebase Crashlytics? Do you have a sample code to show how to save the logs online?

Comment: Hi, I think what you are looking for is [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics). You can see this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60394186/flutter-log-event-with-google-analytics) for more information. Let me know if it helps.